# Change the style of a horizontal rule in Rmarkdown to Microsoft Word

Tags: r, r-markdown

When using `***` to include a horizontal rule in an Rmarkdown document, with a .docx output, the rule is a black solid line.

I am wondering how change the style of the horizontal rule (colour, dashed etc.) automatically for all horizontal rules, similarly to how you can change the style of fonts by adjusting the "styles" in Microsoft Word ([see here](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/articles_docx.html)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how this can be done directly.

For a somewhat hacky workaround you can customise the style of, say, a heading level you aren't currently using to have a bottom border.

In this example, I customised the style for Heading 8 in my_style.docx to have a red striped bottom border.

**.Rmd file:**

```
---
output: 
  word_document:
    reference_docx: my_style.docx
---

Here is a horizontal line

***

Here is a level 8 heading which has a style in my_style.docx with a bottom border

########
```

**Rendered Word doc:**

[image]

**Word style window option to select to make the style change:**

[image]